# WSO2 esb API return decimal instead of integer

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using apache WSO2 ESB server to create the API/web services.
When calling the API, it return the response into the JSON format like below

```
{
   "risks":{"risk":2.0, "ability":8.0, "willingness":2.0}, 
   "typeID":1.0, 
   "id":706.0,
   "name":"MY Test Account"
}
```

I am not sure why API is returning all value in decimal format. like **id and typeid** are integer  but API is returning them automatically in decimal format. Please help me to sort out the issue.

Comment: What is your proxy configurations?

Comment: There is no proxy configuration. Just using the default settings

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in wso2 esb 4.8.1, Nevertheless this has been fixed in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0.

Please refer to [WSO2 ESB JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3019)